# Can I quickly sort Google Sheet via buttons?

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

I've got a Google Sheets document with a lot of data that I often need to sort. Google Sheets offers a sorting feature but I'd personally like button on the header that allows sorting of the rows based on that header, ascending or descending. Another thing that makes this maybe harder is that I have 2 rows working as the header.

Is this possible? How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Data > Filter views**. For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.